# Why do I keep getting this error when I try to install the "caret" package on R on macbook pro?

Tags: r, r-caret

```
library(caret)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> there is no package called ‘recipes’

EDIT: I tried this and it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
> install.packages("recipes")
    
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
recipes 0.1.10 0.1.13             FALSE
    
installing the source package ‘recipes’
    
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/recipes_0.1.13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 633375 bytes (618 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 618 KB
    
* installing *source* package ‘recipes’ ...
** package ‘recipes’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lava’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘recipes’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/recipes’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
    
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/g8/j08h_2ts7gnd8_1lvw0dh08r0000gn/T/Rtmpkwi6gN/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: It says "there is no package called 'recipes'.  Run `install.packages("recipes")`.

Comment: I tried that but this showed up.

Comment: I'm not sure why package dependencies aren't automatically installing, but look at the error.  It now says "there is no package called 'lava'".  So do `install.packages("lava")`. You're welcome to continue to post these errors one at a time, but it might be more efficient for you to apply this logic on your own until you have all "missing" packages installed.